# Rails 3: How to find records with field possibly equals to nil?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like to find all `SongWriter`s with `maiden_name` equals to `my_maiden_name` ?

**Note:** `my_maiden_name` may be `nil`

I tried:

```
SongWriter.where("maiden_name = ?", my_maiden_name)
```

and it works fine except the case where `my_maiden_name = nil`.

When `my_maiden_name = nil`, the generated query is:

```
SELECT `song_writers`.* FROM `song_writers` WHERE (maiden_name = NULL)
```

rather than:

```
SELECT `song_writers`.* FROM `song_writers` WHERE maiden_name IS NULL
```

How could I generalize the active record query to include the case `my_maiden_name = nil` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Hash syntax. ActiveRecord will do the conversion for you.

```
SongWriter.where(:maiden_name => my_maiden_name)
```

When `my_maiden_name` is `nil` it will use `IS NULL`. Otherwise it will use `=`.