# Rails-In ActiveRecord, how to express elegantly for omitting where conditions when given param is nil or a predefined const?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The sql may be like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE field0=#{f0} AND field1=#{f1} AND field2=#{f2};
```

The restriction f0 or f1 or f2 may be nil or a predefined value to state that no restrictions for that field.
How to elegantly express this in Rails using ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash of the attributes and values in your [where query](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where), using [reject](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reject) to remove the empty values:

```
attributes = { field0: 'field0_value', field1: '', field2: 'field2_value' }
MyModel.where( attributes.reject { |k,v| v.blank? } )
```

Will result in:

```
SELECT * FROM my_models WHERE field0='field0_value' AND field2='field2_value'
```

Comment: @keepItSimple good to hear! Please consider marking this answer as "accepted" if it solved your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you have rails 3 this will work `.where(:field0 => f0, :field1 => f1, :field2 => f2)` [Rails 3: How to find records with field possibly equals to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500311/rails-3-how-to-find-records-with-field-possibly-equals-to-nil) If Rails 4, try `.where(field0: f0, field1: f1, field2: f2)`